# Edimax EW-7811 UTC wireless usb adapter

Tags: wireless, adapter, elementary

I'm having quite the trouble of installing drivers for my wireless usb adapter. I have tried different drivers, but none of them work. Someone in the same situtation?

*uname -v*

```
#48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 17 12:56:46 UTC 2018
```

*uname -r*

```
4.13.0-43-generic
```

*lsusb | grep Edimax*

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 7392:a812 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't try even to search.